# Python dynamic property file

Tags: python, dynamic

In python, in a long running program... can we be able to read the updates values from a props file.

for example. i have a properties file (json or ini or props any kind of file)

```
name = bob
id = 123
```

when i start my program with above values and while the program is in running state, when i change the values in the props file to below

```
name = bobby
id = 456
```

could my program be able to read the latest values from the props file ?
This has to happen in the running program

Comment: you'll have to reread the file in order to obtain new values

Comment: Your program would either have a thread that checks the file occasionally for changes, or uses something like `watchdog` to monitor the file for changes. You can also install a signal handler that lets you use something like SIGUSR1 to tell the program to re-read the configuration.

Comment: you can load all those in a custom class acting like a dict and you first modify that dict and this should trigger a modification in the backend.. check python dbm, ConfigParser or pastedeploy